# Embeding web page with changing content

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Im trying to copy this web page https://www.scann3d.com.au/view/v1/scann3dtour/caroandkingi/ and change some words, but when i've tried to copy it, i got this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0095)file:///C:/Users/Emad_/Desktop/3D/www.scann3d.com.au/view/v1/scann3dtour/caroandkingi/index.htm -->
<html class="js flexbox flexboxlegacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths noSelect"><!--<![endif]--><!--<body bgcolor="#131313">--><head class="noSelect"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><script src="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/jsapi"></script>
        <title class="noSelect">Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" class="noSelect">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, user-scrollable=no, minimal-ui" class="noSelect">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" class="noSelect">
        <meta property="og:title" content="Hockingstuart: The Block 2015 Kingi and Caro (Level 2)" class="noSelect">
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="SCANN3D" class="noSelect">
        <meta property="og:description" content="Hockingstuart: The Block 2015 Kingi and Caro (Level 2)" class="noSelect">
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnails/KingiandCaro1.jpg" class="noSelect">

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/propertyfiles/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" class="noSelect">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/propertyfiles/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" class="noSelect">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/propertyfiles/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" class="noSelect">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/propertyfiles/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" class="noSelect">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/propertyfiles/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png" class="noSelect">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/propertyfiles/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" class="noSelect">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/propertyfiles/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" class="noSelect">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/propertyfiles/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" class="noSelect">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/propertyfiles/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png" class="noSelect">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/propertyfiles/favicon.ico" class="noSelect">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/propertyfiles/favicon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192" class="noSelect">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/propertyfiles/favicon-160x160.png" sizes="160x160" class="noSelect">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/propertyfiles/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96" class="noSelect">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/propertyfiles/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" class="noSelect">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/propertyfiles/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" class="noSelect">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c" class="noSelect">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/propertyfiles/mstile-144x144.png" class="noSelect">
        <meta name="msapplication-config" content="https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/propertyfiles/browserconfig.xml" class="noSelect">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/normalize.css" class="noSelect">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/default.css" class="noSelect">
        <script async="" src="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/keen.min.js" class="noSelect"></script><script async="" src="file://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" class="noSelect"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/modernizr.js" class="noSelect"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/html5shiv.min.js" class="noSelect"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/scann3d_styles.css" type="text/css" class="noSelect"><style type="text/css"></style><script type="text/javascript" src="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/saved_resource"></script><link type="text/css" href="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/ui+en,table+en.css" rel="stylesheet"><script type="text/javascript" src="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/webfontloader,format+en,default+en,ui+en,table+en,corechart+en.I.js"></script></head>
    <body class="noSelect" style="background-color: rgb(61, 61, 61);">
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <style class="noSelect">
                html, body, iframe { height: 100%; width: 100%; border: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                overflow-y: hidden;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/jquery.min.js" class="noSelect"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/plugins.js" class="noSelect"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/video-js.css" class="noSelect">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/video.js" class="noSelect"></script>
        
 <script type="text/javascript" class="noSelect">
  var Scann3dPlayerExtensions = {
   initCallback: function () {
    'use strict';
    Scann3dDOM.overlayURL = "https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/player/Scann3d.png";
    Scann3dDOM.displaySplash = true;
    Scann3dDOM.displayOverlay = true;
   }, 
   styleCallback: function () {
    'use strict';
    if (Scann3dDOM.overlayImage !== null) {
     Scann3dDOM.overlayImage.style.top = '95px';
     Scann3dDOM.overlayImage.style.right = '12px';
     Scann3dDOM.overlayImage.style.width = '124px';

     $(Scann3dDOM.overlayImageAnchor).attr('href', 'http://scann3d.com.au/');
    }
   }, 
   timerTickCallback: function () { }
  };
 </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/scann3d_vid.js" class="noSelect"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/scann3d_viewer.js" class="noSelect"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/scann3d_api_analytics.js" class="noSelect"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/scann3d_vid_overlays.js" class="noSelect"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" class="noSelect">
  Scann3dDOM.setFloorIDs('oWJPQ8gFTXq');
                Scann3dVidDOM.setVideoLink('https://scann3d.s3.amazonaws.com/propertyfiles/', '-');
$(function() {
                    if((typeof(Scann3dDOM.ribbonPanelImage)!='undefined') && (Scann3dDOM.ribbonPanelImage!==null)) { Scann3dDOM.ribbonPanelImage.remove(); };
                    if((typeof(Scann3dDOM.ribbonPanelImageLeft)!='undefined') && (Scann3dDOM.ribbonPanelImageLeft!==null)) { Scann3dDOM.ribbonPanelImageLeft.remove(); };
                    if((typeof(Scann3dDOM.ribbonPanelImageCentre)!='undefined') && (Scann3dDOM.ribbonPanelImageCentre!==null)) { Scann3dDOM.ribbonPanelImageCentre.remove(); };
                    if((typeof(Scann3dDOM.ribbonPanelImageRight)!='undefined') && (Scann3dDOM.ribbonPanelImageRight!==null)) { Scann3dDOM.ribbonPanelImageRight.remove(); };
                    if((typeof(Scann3dDOM.ribbonPanelDiv)!='undefined') && (Scann3dDOM.ribbonPanelDiv!==null)) { Scann3dDOM.ribbonPanelDiv.remove(); };
                });
        </script>

        
    
<a id="scann3d-overlay-logo-link" href="http://scann3d.com.au/" target="_blank" alt="Scann3d Web Player Overlay Link" class="noSelect"><img id="scann3d-overlay-logo" src="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/Scann3d.png" alt="Scann3d Web Player Overlay" class="noSelect" style="position: fixed; display: block; top: 95px; width: 124px; height: auto; opacity: 1; z-index: 9; max-width: 40vw; right: 12px;"></a><img id="scann3d-help-button" src="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/help_button.png" alt="Scann3d Web Player Help Button" class="noSelect" style="position: fixed; display: block; bottom: 10px; left: 198px; width: 45px; height: auto; opacity: 0;"><iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="./Scann3d Virtual Tour - 5 Commercial Rd_files/saved_resource.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" autoload="" class="noSelect"></iframe></body></html>
```

but im not able to change any word or i cant find any word inside the html any suggestions?

Comment: "Copying" sounds to me close to copyright law violation. But anyway, it's probably because the words (which we don't know where they are and which words anyway) are stored somewhere in the javascript.

Comment: so is there anyway to change words such as address  2/1A Affleck Street, South Yarra, VIC 3141 to something else

Comment: There is, the address is stored in the request that goes to (the url might change, it looks generated): https://my.matterport.com/api/player/models/oWJPQ8gFTXq . So find out where that response is parsed and replace that parsing method with whatever you want.

Comment: Can i hire you for 1 hour? pleas heres my email ElyarRash@gmail.com contact me there